# How to read all certificates on a server using Python

Tags: python, certificate, certificate-store

I have a certificate parser in Python which only reads PEM format using pyasn1. However, how do I 
 1. Listing all certificates on a server given the IP address

so that my parser may read each of them 1-by-1 to extract the fields?

Comment: By all you mean by port or by SNI or both?

Comment: By port might be a good task for nmap. There's a scanner script for that. To do it by SNI you need to know the hostnames to query first.

Comment: Could you provide the scanner script?
Assuming we have the port number, how would the Python code look like?

Comment: It's an nmap extension script and usually comes with nmap. There are many of them. In Python you have to call nmap and process the result. Setting nmap to XML output might be helpful.

Comment: Could you point me a link to the scripts?
After getting the port number, how would the Python code look like?

Comment: check `ssl.get_server_certificate`

Comment: There is a python nmap lib

Answer (score 5):

To list all certificates on a server given an IP address the high level flow would go like this:

```
For each IP:
    For every port: 
        initiate a TLS/SSL connection
        collect SSL Certificate information
        then do your parsing, extraction etc
```

The standard Python library has the essential you need to get going with the core part:

```
  >>> import ssl
  >>> ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.google.com', 443,))
  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIEgDCCA2igAwIBAgIIcdMVyU ...
  [...]
  \nsaofrQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n'
```

The same works for an IP:

```
>>> ssl.get_server_certificate(('109.88.203.241', 443,))
```

You can then write the scan loop more or less this way:

```
import ssl
for ip in ips_to_scan:
    for port in range(65536):
        try:
            yield ssl.get_server_certificate((ip, port,))
        except:
            pass
```

Note: I am ignoring issues of network politeness, and leaving aside nmap since this is a Python question. The try/except pass is brutal too, but this is an example. You may want to refine the error management of course.

There are many libraries available that deal with this extensively too beyond this and for more advanced stuffs. Some of them include:

- [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze) (GPL)
- [sslscan](https://github.com/DinoTools/pysslscan) (LGPL)
- [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) (MIT)
- [sslchecker](https://github.com/raccoonyy/sslchecker) (MIT)